# Create local debian repository

Tags: repository, debian, package

My goal is to demonstrate creating a local debian repository with controlled versions of tools used (e.g. compiler versions) to make a build system more predictable.

I've tried to follow this example: http://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository

but when I get to the apt-get update stage, I always get a 404 not found on the repository I've added.

The apache2 server is running, I can view the default page installed at http://localhost/html/index.html.

I am trying this with the file fortune-mod_1%3a1.99.1-7_amd64.deb installed to /var/www/debs.  I create the Packages.gz file as the tutorial suggests:

```
dpkg-scanpackages debs /dev/null | gzip -9c > debs/Packages.gz
```

I also add a new file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myppa.list with this line:

```
deb http://localhost debs/
```

I restart the apache2 service just in case:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

still produces this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://localhost/debs/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Is there something basic I'm missing?  Ultimately, I'd like to get this working over a LAN, but first have to get it working on a single machine.

EDIT: I'm doing this on Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT: Show contents of file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myppa.list

Comment: Two remarks: 1- you can always test the url with a web browser or `wget`. If they can't access the repository url, nor will apt. 2- For local repository you can use another protocol: `file:///<local location>`. Apt support this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem.  It was an issue with the default document root being different for the tutorial than on my system.  All I did was move my debs folder to html (document root turns out to be /var/www/html, not just /var/www on my install).  That did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

tldr; use [aptly](https://www.aptly.info)

It's the easiest apt repository management tool I've found and it comes with [neat tutorial](https://www.aptly.info/tutorial/repo/) showing how to create, populate, and publish your own apt repository.

References:

- https://www.aptly.info/
- https://www.aptly.info/tutorial/repo/

Comment: Thanks for that tip - it looks great!